# populating List<> using Array get wrong numbers

Tags: c++, list

I have simple class structure that has an array part of its fields. I want to store this class in a list. The problem is when adding additional class structures to the list it handles it as if it's a direct update and not referenced.

```
 public class TrayLayout
 {
      public int[] inerD { get; set; }

public class TrayLayout
 {
      public int[] inerD { get; set; }

      public TrayLayout(int[] inerD)
      {
           this.inerD = inerD;
       }
 }
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
      public List<TrayLayout> trayL = new List<TrayLayout>();
      public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           int[] aa = new int[2];
           aa[0]=1;
           aa[1]=2;
           //add the new class to TrayLoayout
           trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
           aa[0]=3;
           aa[1]=4;
           //add the new class to TrayLoayout using input array
           trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
           aa[0]=5;
           aa[1]=6;
           //add the new class to TrayLoayout
           trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
           textBox1.Text = "the numbers accepted \n"+ trayL[0].inerD[0].ToString() + " , " +trayL[0].inerD[1].ToString() + " \n" + trayL[1].inerD[0].ToString() + " , " +trayL[1].inerD[1].ToString() + " \n" + trayL[2].inerD[0].ToString() + " , " +trayL[2].inerD[1].ToString() ;

      }
```

I get in TextBoxes it shows the last input 5,6 5,6 5,6 instead of 1,2 3,4 5,6. I must be missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You always refer to the *same* int array, overwriting the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

You have created 1 ArrayObject aa. And you are overwriting the first 2 values, when you assign 3 and 4. And when you assign 5 and 6 you have overwritten 3 and 4.

Create 3 different arrays or make aa[0] to aa[5].

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this:

```
int[] aa = new int[2];
aa[0]=1;
aa[1]=2;
//add the new class to TrayLoayout
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
aa[0]=3;
aa[1]=4;
//add the new class to TrayLoayout
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
aa[0]=5;
aa[1]=6;
//add the new class to TrayLoayout
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(aa));
```

With this:

```
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(new int[]{1,2}));
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(new int[]{3,4}));
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(new int[]{5,6}));
```

**Edit**

You could do it like this:

```
var start=1;
var end=13;
trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(Enumerable.Range(start,end).ToArray()));
```

Comment: what if I have an array 0f 53 that will be heck of coding is there a simple way

Comment: trayL.Add(new TrayLayout(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13})); and so on... not convenint

Comment: Arion 10X 4 the comment but what I shown here is a recreate of the problam, where in the project I have to store 10 barcodes or in other case 53 barcodes IN AN ARRAY and store the class in List<> so is there a esay way to store the data?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the `int` array to the `TrayLayout` class does not make a copy. Each instance of the `TrayLayout` class in your example has a reference to the *same* array, so when you update it following the call to the `TrayLayout` constructor, all your instances of `TrayLayout` see the same values.

Either copy the array internally in the `TrayLayout` constructor, or (as others are suggesting) use different arrays in the constructor calls.

Comment: I tried in the constractor         public TrayLayout(int[] ainerD)
          {
               this.inerD[0] = ainerD[0];
               this.inerD[1] = ainerD[1];
          }
  and nothing was writin

Comment: You are still only capturing a reference. Use something like `this.inerD = new int[ainerD.Length];
Array.Copy(ainerD, this.inerD, ainerD.Length);`